# Update core from 5.33.2 to 5.35.1 generates errors when re-enable modules

Tags: upgrade

Re-enabling non-core modules after update spawned hundreds of this error:

WD civicrm: hook_civicrm_alter_drupal_entity_labels should be updated to  [warning]
pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke().
Array
(
[civi.tag] => deprecated
)

For these modules:
civicrm_contact_match was enabled successfully.                           [ok]
civicrm_contact_match defines the following permissions: modify uf match
civicrm_cron was enabled successfully.                                    [ok]
esoCiviMail was enabled successfully.                                     [ok]
webform_civicrm was enabled successfully.                                 [ok]
civicrmtheme was enabled successfully.                                    [ok]
civicrm_contact_ref was enabled successfully.                             [ok]
civicrm_entity was enabled successfully.                                  [ok]
civicrm_entity defines the following permissions: civicrm_entity.rules.administer, administer CiviCRM Entity

Answer (score 1):

> WD civicrm: hook_civicrm_alter_drupal_entity_labels should be updated to [warning] pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Array ( [civi.tag] => deprecated )

For this,  i think you need to apply https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_entity/pull/238 patch in civicrm_entity module.